# How to apply filters by name and price on list fetched from firebase android

Tags: android, list, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am new to android and i am working on my Practice app in which i am using firebase realtimeDatabase. I have stored some data on the DB and i am getting it in List, which is working fine but there is some problem that i want to apply Filters on my list with Price and Name of the items present in the list. I am unable to do that. i am using Material Chips buttons to apply filters.
i tried some github topics to do this but couldn't do that. Kindly give me some guidelines so that i can do this sorting.

Comment: What exactly have you tried and doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo actually i have a list of some furniture items, and i want to apply sorting on Name and Price basis. this is what i am trying to do so.

Comment: Show us the code then.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this-

```
String name = "Pen";
Integer price = 100;

CollectionReference productRef = firebaseFirestore.collection("products");
productRef.whereEqualTo("name", name).whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("price",price).orderBy("name", Direction.ASCENDING).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

    }
});
```

for more such queries with firestore check this- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#java

Comment: can you sort this name and price on ascending and descending order too ?

Comment: yes, we can, check updated ans.

Comment: The code in your answer is for Cloud Firestore, while OP explicitly mentioned the Realtime Database in their question. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and the API for one doesn't work for the other.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes sir, My Bad I just looked into the question, He is asking about Realtime DB, I thought It Firestore.

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane 
i am using material Filter chip for filter the products on the basis of name and price in ascending or descending order ,how we  can apply filter on the list reterived from Firebase realtime database using material chip